# Pointers and char arrays from strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, uart

Hi I have been reading for hours and still can't grasp the conversions between

```
{
    char i ="adf";
    char foo[];
    char bar[256];
}
```

and adding `*` and `&` makes it more confusing

I have some code that is working.

```
int TX_SEND(char send[])
{
    unsigned char *p_tx_buffer;
    p_tx_buffer = &send[0];
    strcat(send, "\r");
    // Write to the port

    int n = write(fd,&send[0],3);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("Write failed - ");
        return -1;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

code is working but I need help with 2 parts.

1. I want to be able to run this function like kind of like `printf IE TX_SEND("AT+CGMSD=STUFF");` but I am stuck

but before hand I do this alot.

```
 char txsend[] = "at";
 TX_SEND(txsend);
```

2. Also inside my `TX_WRITE()` I am using `write(fd,&send[0],3)`, but it is hardcoded to send 3 bytes from `send[]`. I want this to be dynamic so I can just send strings at any length (realistically they will be less than 300 ASCII chars always).  I tried to do something with a pointer in there but gave up (`*p_tx_buffer` was my beginning attempt).

Comment: use `TX_SEND(char * send)`

Comment: Is this going to be run on a system that doesn't have space for the standard library? In other words, is it not possible to include "string.h" and call strlen() to get the length of the string passed in?

Comment: he's got strcat in there, so i supposed strlen is fine too

Comment: This is for a raspberry pi, I have plenty of space for libraries, is strlen() for constant strings or for string arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want

```
int TX_SEND(char *send)
{


    int n = write(fd,send,strlen(send));
    if (n < 0) {
            perror("Write failed - ");
            return -1;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

you cannot tack on \n to send with strcat. I would add it in the calling function, or declare an intermediate buffer and sprintf to it

like this

```
int TX_SEND(char *send)
{
    char buff[50]; // i dont know a good max size
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%s\n", send);

    int n = write(fd,buff,strlen(buff));
    if (n < 0) {
            perror("Write failed - ");
            return -1;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will read about these functions to better understand them.  I like the char *send, I had no idea how to refer to data "string1" as input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go through your code line-by-line, but I urge you to focus on these facts:

1. chars are chars and strings are strings, and never the twain shall meet.  (They're totally different.)
2. 'x' is a character constant.
3. "x" is a string constant.
4. A string is an array of characters (terminated by `'\0'`).
5. When you mention an array (including a string) in a context where you need its value, what you get is a pointer to the array's first element.
6. When you put a `&` in front of something, what you get is a pointer to that something.
7. When you put a `*` in front of a pointer, what you get is the thing that the pointer points to.

Putting this together, we could write

```
char str[] = "xyz";
char *p = str;       /* per rule 5, this is fine, and p gets a pointer to str's first element */
char c = *p;         /* per rule 7, c gets the first character of str, which is 'x' */
printf("%c\n", c);
```

If you're just starting with C, you may not have come across rule 5 yet.  It will probably surprise you at first.  Learn it well, though: you'll never understand arrays and pointers in C without it.

Comment: Thank you so much for making this plain for me I had a vague idea about 4, 6 and 7 but the rest is new for me.